# Trying to use recursion on Iterated Integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, iterated-integrals

I have the following integral: $$F_3(y)=\int_R |x_1x_2x_3|^{-(1+\alpha)}\;dx_1dx_2dx_3,$$
over the region $R=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}:x_1+x_2+x_3\geq y, |x_1|\geq 1, |x_2|\geq 1,|x_3|\geq 1\right\}$ where $1<\alpha<2$ and $y>1.$

There is no closed form for the integral but I would like to write it in terms of $F_1$ and $F_2$, where $F_1(y)$ and $F_2(y)$ are defined in a similar fashion for $y>1$ . For example, we may first write $$F_3(y)=\int_R |x_1x_2x_3|^{-(1+\alpha)}\;dx_1dx_2dx_3=\int_R |x_1|^{-(1+\alpha)}F_2(y-x_1)\;dx_1.$$

The issue that now arises is that as $x_1$ varies the quantity $y-x_1$ will not be greater than one in some regions. While it is possible to define these $F$ integrals for all $y$, I would like to stay with positive $y$.

If there a general framework to achieve this? Also, would it be easier to evaluate the integral using complex analysis? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $
> \begin{array}{l}
> \ds{R \equiv \braces{\pars{x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}\ \mid\ x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} > y\,;\quad\verts{x_{1}} \geq 1\,,
> \verts{x_{2}} \geq 1\,,\verts{x_{3}} \geq 1}.}
> \\[2mm]
> \ds{\alpha \in \pars{1,2}\quad\mbox{and}\quad y > 1.}
> \end{array}$

---

> Hereafter, $\ds{\bracks{\cdots}}$ is a notation for the
>   [Iverson Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Namely,
>   $\ds{\bracks{\mrm{P}} = 1}$ whenever $\ds{\,\mrm{P}}$
>   $\bbox[#dfe,5px]{\texttt{is true}}$. $\bbox[#dfe,5px]{\texttt{Otherwise}}$, $\ds{\bracks{\mrm{P}} = 0}$.

---

\begin{align}
\mrm{F}_3\pars{y} & \equiv
\int_{R}\verts{x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}}^{\,-\pars{1 + \alpha}}
\,\dd x_{1}\dd x_{2}\dd x_{3}
\\[5mm] & =
\iint_{\verts{x_{1}}\ \geq\ 1 \atop \verts{x_{2}}\ \geq\ 1}
\verts{x_{1}x_{2}}^{\,-\pars{1 + \alpha}}
\int_{\verts{x_{3}}\ \geq\ 1}\verts{x_{3}}^{\,-\pars{1 + \alpha}}
\bracks{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} > y}\dd x_{3}\dd x_{2}\dd x_{1}
\\[1cm] & =
\iint_{\verts{x_{1}}\ \geq\ 1 \atop \verts{x_{2}}\ \geq\ 1}
\verts{x_{1}x_{2}}^{\,-\pars{1 + \alpha}}
\\[5mm] &
\pars{\color{#00f}{\int_{1}^{\infty}x_{3}^{\,-\pars{1 + \alpha}}
\bracks{x_{3} > y - x_{1} - x_{2}}\dd x_{3}} +
\color{#f00}{\int_{1}^{\infty}x_{3}^{\,-\pars{1 + \alpha}}
\bracks{x_{3} < x_{1} + x_{2} - y}\dd x_{3}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\int_{1}^{\infty}x_{3}^{\,-\pars{1 + \alpha}}
\bracks{x_{3} > y - x_{1} - x_{2}}\dd x_{3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{y - x_{1} - x_{2} < 1}\int_{1}^{\infty}x_{3}^{-\alpha - 1}\,\dd x_{3} +
\bracks{y - x_{1} - x_{2} > 1}\int_{y - x_{1} - x_{2}}^{\infty}
x_{3}^{-\alpha - 1}\,\dd x_{3}
\\[5mm] & =
\color{#00f}{{\bracks{x_{2} > y - x_{1} - 1} \over \alpha} +
{\bracks{x_{2} < y - x_{1} - 1} \over \alpha}\,
\pars{y - x_{1} - x_{2}}^{-\alpha}}\label{2}\tag{2}
\\[1cm]
&\color{#f00}{\int_{1}^{\infty}x_{3}^{\,-\pars{1 + \alpha}}
\bracks{x_{3} < x_{1} + x_{2} - y}\dd x_{3}} =
\bracks{x_{1} + x_{2} - y > 1}
\int_{1}^{x_{1} + x_{2} - y}x_{3}^{-\alpha - 1}\dd x_{3}
\\[5mm] = &\
\color{#f00}{{\bracks{x_{2} > y - x_{1} + 1} \over \alpha}\bracks{%
1 - \pars{x_{1} + x_{2} - y}^{-\alpha}}}\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

---

With \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}, \eqref{1} is written as
$\ds{\,\mrm{F}_{3}\pars{y}  = \int_{\verts{x_{1}}\ \geq\ 1}\verts{x_{1}}^{-\pars{1 + \alpha}}\,\mrm{F}_{2}\pars{y - x_{1}}\,\dd x_{1}}$ where:
\begin{align}
\mrm{F}_{2}\pars{z} & \equiv
{1 \over \alpha}\int_{\verts{x_{2}}\ \geq\ 1}\verts{x_{2}}^{-\alpha - 1}
\bracks{x_{2} > z - 1}\,\dd x_{2}\label{4}\tag{4}
\\[5mm] & +
{1 \over \alpha}\int_{\verts{x_{2}}\ \geq\ 1}\verts{x_{2}}^{-\alpha - 1}
\pars{z - x_{2}}^{-\alpha}\bracks{x_{2} < z - 1}\,\dd x_{2}\label{5}\tag{5}
\\[5mm] & +
{1 \over \alpha}\int_{\verts{x_{2}}\ \geq\ 1}\verts{x_{2}}^{-\alpha - 1}
\bracks{x_{2} > z + 1}\,\dd x_{2}\label{6}\tag{6}
\\[5mm] & -
{1 \over \alpha}\int_{\verts{x_{2}}\ \geq\ 1}\verts{x_{2}}^{-\alpha - 1}
\pars{x_{2} - z}^{-\alpha}\bracks{x_{2} > z + 1}\,\dd x_{2}\label{7}\tag{7}
\end{align}

---

**$\ds{x_{2}}$-Integration in Line \eqref{4}:**
\begin{align}
&{1 \over \alpha}\int_{\verts{x_{2}}\ \geq\ 1}\verts{x_{2}}^{-\alpha - 1}
\bracks{x_{2} > z - 1}\,\dd x_{2}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over \alpha}\int_{1}^{\infty}x_{2}^{-\alpha - 1}
\bracks{x_{2} > z - 1}\,\dd x_{2} +
{1 \over \alpha}\int_{1}^{\infty}x_{2}^{-\alpha - 1}
\bracks{x_{2} < 1 - z}\,\dd x_{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{\bracks{z - 1 < 1}\over \alpha}\int_{1}^{\infty}x_{2}^{-\alpha - 1}\,\dd x_{2} +
{\bracks{z - 1 > 1}\over \alpha}\int_{z - 1}^{\infty}x_{2}^{-\alpha - 1}
\,\dd x_{2} +
{\bracks{1 - z > 1}\over \alpha}\int_{1}^{1 - z}x_{2}^{-\alpha - 1}
\,\dd x_{2}
\\[5mm] & =
{\bracks{z < 2}\over \alpha^{2}} +
{\bracks{z > 2}\over \alpha^{2}}\pars{z - 1}^{-\alpha} +
{\bracks{z < 0}\over \alpha^{2}}\bracks{1 - \pars{1 - z}^{-\alpha}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\ds{%
{\bracks{z < 0}\bracks{2 - \pars{1 - z}^{-\alpha}} + \bracks{0 < z < 2} +
\bracks{z > 2}\pars{z - 1}^{-\alpha} \over \alpha^{2}}}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{x_{2}}$-integrations in lines \eqref{5}, \eqref{6} and \eqref{7} are rather similar to the above integration. Can you take it from here ?.